# foreach($q->result() as $row) is looping twice through result set

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, foreach, codeigniter-2

My foreach loop seems to be looping twice! I have this in my model for my CodeIgniter project:

```
public function check_late_in($late){
    $this->db->select('users.title, users.firstname, users.lastname, users.email_address, clock_in_out.user_id, clock_in_out.loggedin');
    $this->db->join('users', 'clock_in_out.user_id = users.id');
    $this->db->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(loggedin) >= ', strtotime($late));
    $q = $this->db->get('clock_in_out');

    foreach($q->result() as $row){

        $data = array();

        $data = array(
            'user_id'  => $row->user_id,
            'assignee' => 88,
            'description' => 'You were LATE!',
            'created'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );

        $q = $this->db->insert('notifications', $data);
    }

    if($q){
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

If I dump $q->result() after the query I get 2 results. However in the loop the data is being duplicated so instead of 2 rows of data I am getting four rows after execution.

Comment: I'd be suspicious of changing the value of $q inside your FOREACH loop.

Comment: You are assigning `$q` for `two` array which is an ambiguous please define your variables unique

Comment: @BigScar why do you say that?

Comment: removing $q changes nothing, still loops

Comment: `echo count($q->result());` what you get?

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare `$data = array()` before beginning of  `foreach` loop

Comment: try  `var_dump($q->result_array()) ;`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason, in my controller I was calling

```
if($this->method){
    $data['foo'] = $this->method;
}
```

So the function was being called twice.

Thanks for the help!